# Impersonating accounts on a forked Ethereum main net using Hardhat

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, buidler, mainnet

I used [the example](https://hardhat.org/guides/mainnet-forking.html#impersonating-accounts) from the Hardhat docs to impersonate an account on a forked network:

```
await hre.network.provider.request({ method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount", params: ["0x...."]} )
```

However, I get "Error: Returned error: unknown account". How should this be done correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

try

```
import { network, ethers } from "hardhat";
await network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
      params: ["0x..........................."],
    });
```

if you use hardhat-ethers

```
 const signer = await ethers.provider.getSigner(
      "0x..........................."
    );
```

Answer (score 7):

**Update Oct 2022**

Impersonating Accounts with Hardhat has a new, simplified API. According to their new [docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks#impersonating-accounts), you can impersonate an account using the `getImpersonatedSigner` method

```js
const impersonatedSigner = await ethers.getImpersonatedSigner("0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
await impersonatedSigner.sendTransaction(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

**viem solution 2024**

Import

```js
import hre from "hardhat";
import { impersonateAccount } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers"
```

impersonate

```js
const whaleWalletAddress = '0xbccA1f5d4dB5FB26310c38b99189C7d43586da46'
await impersonateAccount(whaleWalletAddress)
const [myUserBeingWhale] = await hre.viem.getWalletClients({account: whaleWalletAddress})
```

Should also works for *ethers* (untested)

```js
const myUserSignerBeingWhale = await hre.ethers.getSigner(whaleWalletAddress)
```